# Building a tree of vectors

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to make a simple LISP parser, but I'm stuck on the step where I convert the vector of tokens into a tree of AST nodes.

I create the root of the tree, and then maintain a stack of references into the tree where I currently want to add the next node. The problem is that no matter what I try, it seems that the borrow checker thinks I'm referencing something that doesn't live long enough.

This is the code:

```
pub fn parse(tokens: &Vec<Token>) -> Node {
    let mut root: Vec<Node> = vec![];

    {
        tokens.into_iter().fold(vec![&mut root], handle_token);
    }

    Node::List(root)
}

fn handle_token<'a>(mut stack: Vec<&'a mut Vec<Node>>, token: &Token) -> Vec<&'a mut Vec<Node>> {
    if *token == Token::LParen {
        let new_node = Node::List(vec![]); // Create the new node
        stack[0].push(new_node); // Add it to the tree
        match stack[0][0] {
            Node::List(ref mut the_vec) => stack.push(the_vec), // Finally, add a mutable reference to the new vector so that subsequent nodes will become children of this Node
            _ => panic!(),
        };
    } else if *token == Token::RParen {
        stack.pop();
    } else {
        match *token {
            Token::Identifier(ref identifier) => {
                stack[0].push(Node::Identifier(identifier.to_owned()))
            }
            Token::Number(number) => stack[0].push(Node::Number(number)),
            Token::Str(ref s) => stack[0].push(Node::Str(s.to_owned())),
            Token::EOF => {}
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    stack
}
```

This is the compiler output:

```
error: `stack` does not live long enough
  --> src/parser.rs:30:15
   |
30 |         match stack[0][0] {
   |               ^^^^^ does not live long enough
...
47 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 26:96...
  --> src/parser.rs:26:97
   |
26 | fn handle_token<'a>(mut stack: Vec<&'a mut Vec<Node>>, token: &Token) -> Vec<&'a mut Vec<Node>> {
   |                                                                                                 ^
```

After researching this a bit, it seems like I'm trying to do something completely non-idiomatic to Rust, but I'm not sure. Is there a simple way to make this work, or do I need to rethink this?

I tried to reduce the problem [to a minimal example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f1335809d1c642f16f5a9e71d1c978e):

```
enum Token {
    Start,
    End,
    Value(i32),
}

enum Node {
    List(Vec<Node>),
    Value(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![Token::Start, Token::Value(1), Token::End];
    parse(&v);
}

fn parse(tokens: &Vec<Token>) -> Node {
    let mut root: Vec<Node> = vec![];

    {
        tokens.into_iter().fold(vec![&mut root], handle_token);
    }

    Node::List(root)
}

fn handle_token<'a>(mut stack: Vec<&'a mut Vec<Node>>, token: &Token) -> Vec<&'a mut Vec<Node>> {
    match *token {
        Token::Start => {
            stack[0].push(Node::List(vec![])); // Add the new node to the tree
            match stack[0][0] {
                Node::List(ref mut the_vec) => stack.push(the_vec), // Add a mutable reference to the new vector so that subsequent nodes will become children of this Node
                _ => panic!(),
            };
        },
        Token::End => { stack.pop(); },
        Token::Value(v) => stack[0].push(Node::Value(v)),
    }

    stack
}
```

Comment: It looks like you add something a second time to the stack, without removing the first. But data should have 1 owner, not 2. Can you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That would make it easier to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @wimh mentioned, you're violating ownership.  Let me try to break it down a bit, and see if it makes sense.

`stack[0][0]` gives you a `Node` contained in a mutable borrow of a `Vec`.  You then try to mutably borrow the `Vec` contained in the `Node::List` variant of that `Node`, and add it as a mutable borrow to the outer `Vec` (the `stack`).  If this were allowed, you'd now have the outer `Vec` and the inner `Vec` able to mutate that `Node`'s `Vec` at the same time.

I would try to rethink your design a bit, and see if you can make ownership a bit more clearcut.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a [blog post about modeling graphs using vector indices](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/04/06/modeling-graphs-in-rust-using-vector-indices/) I decided to try a similar approach. The resulting code works and is a lot simpler:

```
type NodeIndex = usize;

pub fn parse(tokens: &Vec<Token>) -> Node {
    let mut root: Node = Node::List(vec![]);

    {
        tokens.into_iter().fold((&mut root, vec![]), handle_token);
    }

    root
}

fn add_node(tree: &mut Node, indices: &Vec<NodeIndex>, node: Node) -> NodeIndex {
    let node_to_add_to = get_node(tree, indices);

    match node_to_add_to {
        &mut Node::List(ref mut vec) => {
            vec.push(node);
            vec.len() - 1
        },
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}

fn get_node<'a>(tree: &'a mut Node, indices: &Vec<NodeIndex>) -> &'a mut Node {
    indices.iter().fold(tree, |node, index| match node {
        &mut Node::List(ref mut vec) => &mut vec[*index],
        _ => panic!(),
    })
}

fn handle_token<'a>(state: (&'a mut Node, Vec<NodeIndex>), token: &Token) -> (&'a mut Node, Vec<NodeIndex>) {
    let (tree, mut index_stack) = state;

    match *token {
        Token::LParen => {
            let new_index = add_node(tree, &index_stack, Node::List(vec![]));
            index_stack.push(new_index);
        },
        Token::RParen => { index_stack.pop(); },
        Token::Identifier(ref identifier) => { add_node(tree, &index_stack, Node::Identifier(identifier.to_owned())); },
        Token::Number(number) => { add_node(tree, &index_stack, Node::Number(number)); },
        Token::Str(ref s) => { add_node(tree, &index_stack, Node::Str(s.to_owned())); },
        Token::EOF => { assert!(index_stack.is_empty()); },
    }

    (tree, index_stack)
}
```